# Hide non-active worksheets in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I have a UserForm in Excel 2013 that cleans up the Excel page for the user prior to manipulation. The public Module has the following VBA code:

```
Sub ShowForm()
    With ActiveWorkbook
        .Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
        .Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False 'Hide didn't work
        .Worksheets("Sheet3").Visible = False 'Hide didn't work
    End With

    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

How can I hide Worksheets 2 and 3 and activate or make Worksheet 1 visible? The code should mimic right-clicking a tab and selecting "Hide". The above code throws a `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`.

Comment: then `ActiveWorkbook` points to a workbook that has only 1 (if `.Worksheets(2)...` errors) or 2 (if `.Worksheets(3)...` errors) worksheets. Query`?ActiveWorkbook.Name` in immediate window to know which workbook you're actually pointing to. But the best would be using `With Workbooks("MyWorkbookName")` and ensure you're dealing with the wanted workbook

Comment: I tried using `With Workbooks...End With` and get the same `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range.`. I also used the immediate window to determine the current `?ActiveWorkbook.Name`. I was using the correct ActiveWorkbook.

Comment: I see you edited and now use `.Worksheets("Sheet 2")` (and the likes). So the point is now whether your `Workbooks("MyWorkbookName")` actually has any sheet named after `"Sheet 1"` (if `.Worksheets("Sheet 1")` errors) or `"Sheet 3"`  (if `.Worksheets("Sheet 3")` errors) .  Which line errors out?

Comment: @Andy you said you are using Excel 2013, are you sure the sheet name is "Sheet 1" please check the exact sheet name. In 2013 default sheet name is "Sheet1" without space.

Comment: I only changed Worksheets to "string" values to eliminate debate over the index values. If I use index values for the worksheets argument, I get the run-time error. If I use the worksheet names (which I verified exactly), I get the run-time error. The debugger errors out at the `.Worksheets("Sheet2").Visible = False` line. I believe maybe the `Visible` method / property doesn't work with the Worksheets collection. The List properties dialogue box doesn't show up when I press Ctrl+J.

Comment: OK..I found an extra space in one of my Worksheets name. It works now. Very frustrating! Thank you everyone for the support.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're after hiding everything except the active sheet.  Try this code - it doesn't depend on the sheet name.

```
Sub Test()

    SheetVisibility 'Hide all except active sheet.

    MsgBox "All except `" & ActiveSheet.Name & "` hidden."

    SheetVisibility True 'Unhide all sheets.

End Sub

Sub SheetVisibility(Optional ShowAll As Boolean = False)

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet

    For Each wrkSht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If wrkSht.Name <> ActiveSheet.Name Then
            wrkSht.Visible = IIf(ShowAll, xlSheetVisible, xlSheetHidden)
        End If
    Next wrkSht

End Sub
```